# Batch random number add or subtract value

Tags: batch-file, random

I was trying something new in batch files, and started testing with randomly generated numbers. the only problem that i got is adding values after i got the randomly generated numbers. For instance, i would like to add 300 to a randomly generated number, then how do i do this?
***This is what i have:***

```
cls
@echo off
set /a KNW=%RANDOM% %%101
echo Knowledge: %KNW%
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
%KNW%+300
echo %KNW%
PAUSE
EXIT
```

[IMG: This is my result, i hope someone could help me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ThTu.png)

Comment: Why wouldn't you continue to use the `SET /A` command to do your math?

Comment: And for future reference I think it would be a lot easier for you to copy and paste from the cmd window then posting a screen shot of your output.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped. I thought when i would put "set /a KNW+=300" instead of "%KNW%+300" it would add 300 everytime, but it doesn't. Thanks again.

Comment: Works fine when I use it.  Don't know what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `set /a` to add the numbers together:

```
cls
@echo off
set /a KNW=%RANDOM% %%101
echo Knowledge: %KNW%
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /a KNW=%KNW%+300
echo %KNW%
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any problems using the assignment operators.

This works just fine for me.

```
@echo off
set /a KNW=%RANDOM% %%101
echo Knowledge: %KNW%
echo ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
set /a KNW+=300
echo Knowledge: %KNW%
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Output

```
Knowledge: 21
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Knowledge: 321
Press any key to continue . . .
```